# WCF Service host using ServiceHostFactory with Multiple Binding

Tags: wcf, factory, nettcpbinding, basichttpbinding, servicehost

I have created WCF service to host on IIS.
I am using ServiceHostFactory method to host my service(using Unity as DI).

I want to host my service using multiple binding, over the HTTP as well as over the TCP.

I tried giving base address, but its not taking. still giving me error as Service registered with HTTP schema.

Below code snippet might give you and idea.

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(
                                Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        MyServiceHost serviceHost = new MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

        //configure container
        MyFactory.Register();

        return serviceHost;
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>    
<services>
  <service name="My.Service.MyService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/MyService/"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/MyService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="Question" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="My.Contract.IQuestionContract" />
    <endpoint address="Answer" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="My.Contract.IAnswerContract" />
    <endpoint address="Question" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="My.Contract.IQuestionContract" />
    <endpoint address="Answer" binding="netTcpBinding"  contract="My.Contract.IAnswerContract" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServicebehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Can anyone suggest me what can be done?

Main thing,
Is it possible to host service using ServiceHostFactory with Multiple Binding?

If Yes, can anyone help me how?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to remove base net.tcp address and specify full address on endpoint.

Comment: I tried giving full address in binding, it is not working.

"No protocol binding matches the given address 'net.tcp://localhost:9001/MyService/Question'."

Comment: Did you try to remove base address as well?

Comment: Yes.I removed base address also.